# How to capture event from apple remote?

Tags: macos, nsevent, media-keys

I want to capture events from an apple remote in a macOS App.

I tried to use EventTap to capture CGEvent from the system and found it do send an event. Then I turn it into NSEvent, then found the data1 and data2 of all buttons are all the same. I'm very confused now.

Comment: What is the type of the event?

Comment: It's subtype 211